# Changing python sequence size during iteration

Tags: python, iteration, sequence

Implementation of `bytes.join` method, implemented [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/58086058/#l-8) includes code that protects from size changes during iteration:

```
    if (seqlen != PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(seq)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                        "sequence changed size during iteration");
        goto error;
    }
```

How is it possible to modify an iterable sequence inside `bytes.join` call and why the above code is necessary? Or maybe it's not necessary and redundant?

Comment: Why do you want to change the size of the sequence while you iterate it? This is probably a bad idea. Show us your code, maybe there's a better way.

Comment: I'm interested about why the mentioned code snippet is in the implementation of the 'join' method, that's all.

Comment: Is this the underlying C-code for Python's `str.join`? How should the result of `join` look like if the sequence changes? Anyhow, strings are immutable, so their byte sequence should not change in the first place...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pass in a list object to `bytes.join()`, you could potentially add elements to the the list in another thread while the `bytes.join()` call is iterating.

The `bytes.join()` method has to make two passes over the sequence; once to calculate the total length of the `bytes` objects contained, a second time to then build the actual output `bytes` object. Changing the number of items while iterating over it would put a spanner in that calculation.

You normally couldn't do this to the list as the GIL is not released, but if any of the objects in the list are *not* `bytes` objects the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) is used instead. As the [a comment on the original patch states](http://bugs.python.org/issue15958):

> The problem with your approach is that the sequence could be mutated while another thread is running (`_getbuffer()` may release the GIL). Then the pre-computed size gets wrong.

Comment: Not `__getitem__` - the sequence is guaranteed to be a tuple or list thanks to PySequence_Fast. Threads that don't respect the GIL might be a problem, but most code assumes such threads won't interfere with their work. I'm inclined to blame the `_getbuffer` call; I believe that allows the sequence elements to run arbitrary code.

Comment: @user2357112: Yeah, I was trying to build a case and discovered that arbitrary sequences are turned into a list first, and list subclasses have their `__getitem__` bypassed. The buffer interface is also not helping here, as that requires C API access.

Comment: @user2357112: in other words, this is only a problem for C code mucking with the list object, or threading.

Comment: The check seems to have gone in in [the same change that added the use of `_getbuffer`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/16285c1b4dda).

Comment: @user2357112: yes, but `_getbuffer` either takes the `bytes` content, or if it isn't a `bytes` object, uses the buffer protocol to access the items. See http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d0ff527c53da/Objects/bytesobject.c#l15

Comment: @user2357112: Would the buffer protocol potentially trigger a GIL release? Because without a GIL release my thread switch theory also doesn't hold.

Comment: Can you please point to a location in source code where _getbuffer releases the GIL?

Comment: @pbp it doesn't itself release it. It calls code that potentially could. Say the buffer is backed by  a harddisk and requires (slow) I/O operations; the buffer implementation would do well to release the GIL then. At that moment another thread could be switched in that alters the list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but it is possible to create a pure python case file that triggers this behavior?

Comment: @pbp: you need a) an extension that provides a type that implements the buffer interface *and* releases the GIL when you use it, b) two threads, one that adds to or removes elements (of the aforementioned type) from list, the other that tries to use the same list for with `bytes.join()`. Manipulating the list from threads can all be done in pure Python; it is the extension that releases the GIL part that either requires you to code something up in C yourself or to find an existing extension. I currently don't know of any, but I haven't actively looked for one.